# Keycloak password hashing alghoritm md5

Tags: md5, keycloak

I need to use the md5 hashing algorithm in my keycloak. I know that keycloak does not support md5? Is there any possibility to extend the list of hashing keycloak algorithms with the md5 algorithm?

Update:
I understand that md5 is not recommended but because of the installation with a very old system I have to use it.

Comment: For what do you need md5 hashing in the Keycloak?

Comment: @JanGaraj for hashing password

Answer (score 8):

Keycloak supports only PBKDF2.

> The only built-in and default algorithm available is PBKDF2.

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#password-policy-types

You can create a custom module (SPI) which implements `PasswordHashProvider`.

See also:
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_providers

The following may be a good example.

https://github.com/leroyguillaume/keycloak-bcrypt